# Find lower value of cosine function

Tags: trigonometry

Assume the figure below shows a cosine with a period of $2 \pi$. As you can see it is shifted up by $\Theta_m$, which is a known value. We also know the area below zero, $F_d$. I'm trying to find an expression for $\Theta_a$, the lowest point of the cosine.

[image: Figure showing the cosine function with area]

My idea is to express the integral of the function with limits for $y=0$.
$$y = a \cos(x) + Θ_m$$
$$Θ_a = Θ_m - a$$

The integral would give:
$$F_d = \left[a \sin(x) +Θ_m x + C\right]_{x_1}^{x_2}$$

The limits I find to be:
$$x_1 = \cos^{-1}( -Θ_m / a)$$
$$x_2 = 2π - \cos^{-1}( -Θ_m / a)$$

Inserting these limits gets rather messy, and I struggle to see that I will be left with a clear expression of $a$ with regards to $F_d$.

Am I missing a simple trick, or is there some simplification that I should use. I will be left with
$\sin( \cos^{-1}( x ) )$ which I know is $\sqrt{1−x^2}$ , but it still seems very messy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $Θ_m$ is the midline of the cosine, I'm looking for an expression of $Θ_a$ with regards to $Θ_m$ and $F_d$.

Comment: sorry, I deleted the $-1$ while editing. The answer is $\Theta_m-1$

Comment: this is because the original midline is $0$. If you're translating the function up by $\Theta_m$, the midline also moves up by $\Theta_m$ and so does the minimum value ( which was originally $-1$).

Comment: @DS the amplitude is unknown a

Comment: @AlexK the question only mentions shifted up by $\Theta_m$, which I'm assuming translation without scaling.

Comment: @LuxNo you can at least simplify a bit by looking at only half of the symmetric area.

Comment: @AlexK is correct, the amplitude has to be derived from the area $F_d$, and since we know the periode I belive it should be possible.

Comment: @AlexK: Yes, it might simply things, but will give the same answer. I end up with a quite complex expression for $F_d = ...$ which I have a hard time converting to $a = ...$

Comment: @LuxNo have you done horizontal scaling or is the period still $2\pi$?

Comment: @DS Sorry if I was missing some information. The period is 2π.

Comment: Without doing the messy algebra myself, I don't have clear advice. You could try changing the parameters, like making $\Theta_m= ua$. Sometimes a simplification becomes obvious *after* you've worked through the whole mess and things cancel.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I prefer to add a separate answer.*

If you look in comments from @David K., the problem *"depends  on what sign $F_d$ has"*

Back to @Max I's answer, let

$$A=\frac{2\pi \Theta_m-F_d}{\Theta_m}\qquad \text{and} \qquad x=\frac{ \Theta_m}a$$

So, the equation to be solved for $x$ write

$$\color{blue}{A=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\cos ^{-1}(-x)}$$

The rhs looks like an hyperbole and , for an approximation, we could expand it as a series

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\cos ^{-1}(-x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi
   }{2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{x^5}{80}+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Using power series reversion
$$x=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{\pi }{2 A^2}+\frac{2+\pi ^2}{4 A^3}+\frac{\pi 
   \left(6+\pi ^2\right)}{8
   A^4}+\frac{26+36 \pi ^2+3 \pi ^4}{48 A^5}+$$
$$\frac{\pi  \left(130+60 \pi ^2+3 \pi ^4\right)}{96 A^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{A^7}\right)$$

Checking for a few values of A

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 4 & 0.440692 &  0.455068 \\
 5 & 0.303157 &  0.305313 \\
 6 & 0.231363 &  0.231871 \\
 7 & 0.187278 &  0.187434 \\
 8 & 0.157416 &  0.157473 \\
 9 & 0.135824 &  0.135848 \\
 10 & 0.119472 &  0.119483 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which seems to be decent. For sure, adding more terms would make it better.

What you could do is to use this as the starting point and make one iteration of Newton method. For example, for $A=4$
, the first iterate would be $x=0.454559$.

**Edit**

We could do much better using more terms in the initial expansion. After series reversion, we can transform the new series into its $[n,n+1]$ Padé approximant $P_n$.

For example
$$P_3= \frac{A(a_0+a_1 A+a_2 A^2) }{b_0+b_1 A+b_2 A^2+b_3A^3+a_2A^4 }$$ where
$$a_0=6 \left(1162-237 \pi ^2+105 \pi ^4\right) \qquad
a_1=36 \pi  \left(79-70 \pi ^2\right)$$
$$a_2=840 \left(3 \pi ^2-7\right)$$
and
$$b_0=-1771 \qquad b_1=-9 \pi  \left(382-149 \pi ^2+35 \pi ^4\right)$$
$$b_2=6 \left(1652-684 \pi ^2+315 \pi ^4\right) \qquad b_3=12 \pi  \left(482-315 \pi ^2\right)$$
whose error is
$$\frac{253 \pi  \left(166-35 \pi ^2\right)}{33600 \left(3 \pi^2-7\right) A^8}\sim -\frac{3}{16\,A^8}$$

Repeating the same calculations as above,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 4 & 0.454779 &  0.455068 \\
 5 & 0.305301 &  0.305313 \\
 6 & 0.231870 &  0.231871 \\
 7 & 0.187434 &  0.187434 \\
 8 & 0.157473 &  0.157473 \\
 9 & 0.135848 &  0.135848 \\
 10 & 0.119483 &  0.119483 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is much better.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to get correct values from this either. 
Looking at it in terms of units, in my problem y-axis is temperature, and x-axis is time. The area $F_d$ has unit $time*temperature$. $x$ is a unitless value, as its division of temperature by temperature. This means that A also should be unitless since $x = 1/A$, but from the first expression of $A$, it will have unit $time$. To me this signals that something is wrong, even though the math seems correct. What do you think?

Comment: As I was writing the comment above, I noticed what I belive is a mistake:

$$A=\frac{2\pi \Theta_m-F_d}{\boldsymbol{2}\Theta_m}\qquad \text{and} \qquad x=\frac{ \Theta_m}a$$

Adding the $2$ in the denominator for $A$ actually made my Excel test work. For values that gives a small area it has a bad fit, but for larger areas (which is more realistic in my case) it actually is quite good.

Thank you all very much. I'm new to the site, and don't know if I can reward you in any way, but you were all very helpful!

Comment: @LuxNo. Please, let me know since I like this problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: However, I have not followed up on your suggestion to make one iteration of Newton method, as I must admit I'm not sure how to do this. Could it make the solution even better?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on the right way, in order to find $ \Theta _{a} $, you have to find the amplitude $ a $ of your function. You already found limits
$$x_{2} = 2\pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right ),$$
$$x_{1} = \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right ) $$
of the integral we use to compute the area of the highlighted figure:
$$\int_{\cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{1a} \right )}^{2\pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right )} \left (a\cos \left ( x \right ) + \Theta _{m}  \right )dx = \left ( a \sin x +  \Theta _{m} x \right )_{\cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right )}^{2\pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right )} \\= 2a \sin\left ( \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right ) \right ) + 2 \Theta _{m} \pi - 2 \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right )\\ =  2a \sqrt{1 - \left ( \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right )^{2}} + 2 \Theta _{m} \pi - 2 \cos^{-1} \left ( - \frac{\Theta _{m}}{a} \right ) = Area$$
Now, (given that I haven't made any mistakes) you just have to solve the last equation for $ a $ and plug it in $$\Theta_{a} = \Theta_{m} + a$$
to get your answer.

Comment: I suppose a typo : isn't $-2a \sqrt{\cdots}$ ?

Comment: $\Theta_m\left(2\pi-2\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{\Theta _m}{a}\right)\right)=2\Theta_m\pi-2\Theta _m\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{\Theta _m}{a}\right)\neq2\Theta_m\pi-2\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{\Theta _m}{a}\right).$

Comment: Thank you Max, I reached the same answer, except with the two corrections mentioned by @ClaudeLeibovici and DavidK. This will be the negative area.

Comment: @LuxNo. For the negative area, have a look at my second answer. Please, let me know if this works. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

*This has modified after @David K's comment and answer.*

Starting from @David K's answer, let
$$A=\frac{F_d}{2\Theta_m}\qquad \text{and} \qquad x=\frac{ \Theta_m}a$$ So, the equation to be solved for $x$ write
$$\color{blue}{A=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}-\cos ^{-1}(x)}$$ The rhs looks like an hyperbole and , for an *approximation*, we could expand it as a series
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}-\cos ^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\pi
   }{2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{x^5}{80}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
Using power series reversion
$$\color{red}{x=\frac{1}{A}-\frac{\pi }{2 A^2}+\frac{2+\pi ^2}{4 A^3}-\frac{\pi 
   \left(6+\pi ^2\right)}{8 A^4}+}$$ $$\color{red}{\frac{26+36 \pi ^2+3 \pi ^4}{48
   A^5}-\frac{\pi  \left(130+60 \pi ^2+3 \pi ^4\right)}{96
   A^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{A^7}\right)}$$

Checking for a few values of $A$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
4 & 0.179446 &  0.182505 \\
 5 & 0.153302 &  0.153997 \\
 6 & 0.133056 &  0.133261 \\
 7 & 0.117409 &  0.117481 \\
 8 & 0.105032 &  0.105062 \\
  9 & 0.095014 &  0.095028 \\
 10 & 0.086743 &  0.086750 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

which seems to be decent. For sure, adding more terms would make it better.

What you could do is to use this as the starting point and make one iteration of Newton method. For example, for $A=4$, the first iterate would be $x=0.182453$.

**Edit**

To show how good is the first series expansion, consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{\frac 1{10}}^1\Bigg[\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}-\cos ^{-1}(x)-S_n \Bigg]^2\,dx$$ where $S_n$ is the expansion to $O(x^{2n+1})$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \Phi_n \\
 1 & 4.972\times 10^{-5} \\
 2 & 1.133\times 10^{-5} \\
 3 & 3.838\times 10^{-6} \\
 4 & 1.635\times 10^{-6} \\
 5 & 8.090\times 10^{-7} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I think while changing variables to $A$ and $x$ you inserted the missing factor of $\Theta_m$ in one of the terms of Max I's answer, but misplaced a factor of $2.$

Comment: @DavidK. You are correct. I shall restart with your formula.

Comment: Thank you for this. The intuition to see the expression as an hyperbole is far above my level. Similarly I'm not really able to check the power series reversion, but I've tried to use your formula in a test now. 

I set $a = Θm - Θa$ into $x = Θm / a$, giving me

$$Θa = Θm - \frac{Θm}{\frac{1}{A}-\frac{\pi}{2A^2}+\cdots +O \left ( \frac{1}{A^7} \right ) } $$

I made an Excel-sheet to test the formula, but it doesn't give me correct values. 
Quick question: Should I do anything with the O ?

I have tested that I get the same values as you for A=4 and A=10, so formula seems correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: To explain my Excel-attempt: I made a cosine function with variable amplitude $a$ and vertical shift $Θm$. I then calculate the area $F_d$. Now I have a value for $Θm$ and $A$ in the formula in my previous comment. I vary my parameters, but the value for $Θa$ is varying a lot, and small changes in $Θm$ can make it go from positive to negative. 

The way I see it, for small values of $A$ your $x$ will become a very large number, and $Θa$ will approach $Θm$ in those cases, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to integrate the shaded area in the figure, rather than integrating from left to right is to integrate from top to bottom.

Solving the equation $y = a \cos(x) + Θ_m$ for $x,$ we find that
the line $y = t$ intersects the curve at
$$ x = \arccos\left(\frac{t - \Theta_m}{a}\right) $$
and at
$$ x = 2 \pi - \arccos\left(\frac{t - \Theta_m}{a}\right) $$
if $-a < t - \Theta_m < a.$
The length of the portion of that line in the shaded area is therefore
$$ f(t) = 2 \pi - 2\arccos\left(\frac{t - \Theta_m}{a}\right). $$

Since $\pi - \arccos(\theta) = \arccos(-\theta),$ we can also write

$$ f(t) = 2\arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m - t}{a}\right). $$

Integrate this from $t = \Theta_a = \Theta_m - a$ to $t = 0$:

$$
\lvert F_d\rvert =
\int_{\Theta_m - a}^0 2\arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m - t}{a}\right)\,\mathrm dt.
$$

Substituting $u = \dfrac{\Theta_m - t}{a},$
write $\mathrm dt = -a \,\mathrm du,$
and we have $u = 1$ when $t = \Theta_m - a$ and $u = \dfrac{\Theta_m}{a}$
when $t = 0,$ so

\begin{align}
\int_{\Theta_m - a}^0 2\arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m - t}{a}\right)\,\mathrm dt
&= \int_1^{\Theta_m/a} -2a\arccos\left(u\right)\,\mathrm du \\
&= \left.-2a\left(u\arccos(u)- \sqrt{1 - u^2}\right)\right|_1^{\Theta_m/a} \\
&= -2a\left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right)
           - \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right)^2}\right)\\
&= 2a\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right)^2}
    -2\Theta_m \arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right).
\end{align}

Now you just need to solve for $a$ in
$$
\lvert F_d\rvert
 = 2a\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right)^2}
    -2\Theta_m \arccos\left(\frac{\Theta_m}{a}\right).
$$

Equations like this typically cannot be solved in closed form, so you will need to use some kind of numerical method.

---

I took the absolute value of $F_d$ above because if you follow the convention that area below the $x$-axis is negative, you will use a negative number for $F_d,$ but if you follow the convention that all area is positive you will of course use a positive number. In any case the magnitude of $F_d$ is unambiguous.

Comment: Funny situation ! I think that your rhs is $-F_d$. Could you check ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It depends on what sign $F_d$ has. I assumed positive, but if you integrate $y = a \cos(x) + \Theta_m$ over $x$ between the two zeros of $y$ you will get a negative integral. For $\Theta_m=0$ my formula gives a positive result because I assumed we would simply measure the magnitude of the area and not assign a negative sign to it.

Comment: Thank you for this alternative approach. I've verified that this solution is equal to the one above (Max with corrections) since 

$$\pi - arccos(-x) = arccos(x)$$

I also agree with your use of positive area.